# Random single quotes being added to option

Tags: bash, rsync

I'm trying to do an rsync like this in a bash script;

```
rsync -e "ssh ${flags_ssh}" -avRz --rsync-path="sudo rsync" $direcNew $(eval echo ${user_name})@$(eval echo ${instance_address}):$(eval echo ${mountdir}`)
```

However, when I run this using bash -x like this:

```
bash -x ./myscript
```

I get that it's trying to run that command except with the option rsync-path looking like

```
'--rsync-path=sudo rsync'
```

How do I prevent this? I need the double quotes to stay and the single quotes to go away, I don't know why it's happening, and I've tried endless combinations of eval and backslashes with no success.

Comment: You don't. When parsing the command `--rsync-path` is for the path to the rsync executable on the remote machine. `rsync` will automatically single quote the path to prevent failure due to the space in the path provided. You can provide commands so long as they do not change `stdin/stdout`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to prevent this. What's happening is that when the shell parses `--rsync-path="sudo rsync"`, it removes the quotes (after they have the intended effect of having the space treated as part of the argument, rather than a separator between arguments). Then, when it sees it's in -x mode, it comes up with a representation that would have led to the space being treated that way, and prints that. It could print any equivalent representation, including (but not limited to) any of these:

```
--rsync-path="sudo rsync"
"--rsync-path=sudo rsync"
--rsync-path=sudo\ rsync
--rsync-path=sudo" "rsync
'--rsync-path=sudo rsync'
$'--rsync-path=sudo rsync'
...etc
```

The fact that it picked a different representation than you did is not important, because these are all fully equivalent -- they all result in exactly the same thing being passed as an argument to `rsync`, so you don't need to worry about it.

You also intrinsically *can't* "fix" it, because by the time the shell prints its interpretation of your command, it's already forgotten which representation you happened to use -- it only knows the resulting argument that's going to be passed to `rsync`. In order to get it to print something else, you'd have to be passing a different actual argument to `rsync`, and that would break your `rsync` command.